# Problems with MSXML2.SERVERXMLHTTP in Classic ASP

Tags: com, asp-classic, httprequest

Right now I'm trying to connect from a Classic ASP VBScript page to an ASP.NET page via HTTPS using this pattern:

```
Dim url
Set url = "https://domain/dir/dir/dir/Page.aspx?foo=1&bar=2"
Set objxmlhttp = server.CreateObject("MSXML2.SERVERXMLHTTP")

objxmlhttp.Open "POST", url, False 

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Response.Write "Ready state is: " & objxmlhttp.readystate & "<br>"
    Call UnAuthorizedUsage("HTTP_VALIDATE_OPEN")
End If

objxmlhttp.Send
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Response.Write "Ready state is: " & objxmlhttp.readystate & "<br>"
    Call UnAuthorizedUsage("HTTP_VALIDATE_SEND")
End If
On Error GoTo 0:

If objxmlhttp.Status = 200  then
    If objxmlhttp.responsetext = "Blah blah blah" Then
        Response.Write "Everything works!"
End if
Set objxmlhttp = Nothing
```

Everything is communicating properly when I'm run this on my local machine, but when I move it to the production server, it just breaks. I get stuck on readystate 1, and there is no communication whatsoever.

However, the strange thing is, when I put in a bogus URL, the error message's ready state is still 1 ([as per the documentation, 1 is "**server connection established**"](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_http.asp)). This leads me to believe that this script isn't able to connect to anything at all.

Is there something I'm missing? What network settings could there be that can be blocking this from happening?

Thank you

Comment: Comment `On Error GoTo 0:` and see.

Comment: @Rufus Still giving me readystate 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run the [ProxyCFG tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289481) on the server?

Comment: It looks like a proxy is in place. What would I have to do to bypass this? Right now I'm thinking the following: *proxycfg -p myproxyserver:8081 "prodserver.com; localhost;"*

Comment: It looks like you would run **proxycfg -d**, but i've never had to run it, I've had our IT people mess with it though.

Comment: Unfortunately even after I did **proxycfg -d** on the server, I'm still having the same issue with it being stuck on readystate 1.

Comment: Did you try with your mentioned settings? the proxycfg -p

Comment: Yes, still no good. I've tried different combinations in the bypass field, such as "*.mydomain.com; <local>;", "mysubdomain.domain.com; localhost; <local>;" and etc